# Would this data model be considered correct

Tags: sql-server, entity-relationship, data-modeling, erd

I'm new to data modelling and have started following tutorials to learn more.

I am trying to create a model for a hypothetical scenario and am struggling to validate what I have created to see if it is what would be considered a correct data model.

Essentially all im trying to do is correctly store data in a normalised form. In my scenario there are 3 types of people and each share some attributes and have one set of contact details each.

Does the below data model look feasible?

[image]

Comment: You should have a one-to-zero-or-one relationship between the Person and related tables.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between person and one of defendant, magistrate, or staff-member is a case of the class/subclass pattern.  There are two common ways of modeling this pattern in relational tables.

One way is called "Class Table Inheritance".  You can find out more by visiting this tag:  [class-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance) or by searching the web for Martin Fowler's treatment of the same subject.  Your design resembles this design.

Another way is called "Single Table Inheritance", which you can also research the same way. [single-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/single-table-inheritance).  It's simpler, and works ok in some cases.  You deal with fewer joins, but you deal with more NULLS.

Many people who go for class table inheritance also apply a technique called "Shared Primary Key".  [shared-primary-key](/questions/tagged/shared-primary-key).  Using this technique, Defendant, Magistrate, and Staff_Member would each use a copy of person_id as the primary key.  This primary key also functions as a foreign key.  Shared primary key enforces the one-to-one nature of the IS-A relationships that exist in this case.

If you want to go further in data modeling, you might want to learn ER modeling as a distinct data model from the relational model.  What you've done here is essentially to use ER diagramming to diagram a relational model.  There's nothing wrong with that, but it obscures a whole new field of study, generally called conceptual data modeling.

If you generate an ER model at the conceptual level, you don't attempt to implement it in terms of tables.  There is a diagramming convention in ER that goes under the name "generalization/specialization"  that allows you to depict a class/subclass situation, while remaining silent on how it's going to be implemented.

Conceptual data models have an area of usefulness, in addition to relational data modeling.  What makes conceptual data models useful is precisely the fact that they present the information requirements without stating how those requirements are going to be met.

Once you are proficient at creating conceptual data models, it's not hard to convert one of them to a relational model.

This may be more than you bargained for, but since you are taking on learning modeling, I thought I'd survey some of the field for you.